# Woocomerce composite product cambiar de una sola columna a grid

Tags: woocommerce

Hola buenas tardes tengo una web en la que me gustaría usar una rejilla (grid) en lugar de una lista de productos,(en la se muestran de uno en uno), para que sea la pagina mas usable.

ahora mismo se ve así https://cctvyalarmas.com/comprar/configurador-alarma-ajax/#elige-los-accesorios
y esto no es practico ya que no se ven todos los productos de un solo vistazo.

muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: como podría cambiarlo para que se vea como un grip en vez de una lista con un solo producto?